# How to pass parameter from ajax to spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to add a parameter to an ajax request and send it back to the controller.

Can you please help me to troubleshoot this problem. I do not understand why in the controller I get null value for the startDate/stopDate parameters.

Thanks

```
function getFilterParams() {
    return {
        "type" : "GET",
        "url" : "results",
        "async" : true,
        "data" : {
            "startDate" : $('#startDatePicker').find("input").val(),
            "stopDate" : $('#stopDatePicker').find("input").val(),
            success : function() {
                alert("success ");
            },
            error : function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    };
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<Results> findAllForDataTables(HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println(request.getParameter("startDate")); // This shows nothing

        DatatablesCriterias dataTableCriterias = DatatablesCriterias.getFromRequest(request);
        // Add the extra parameters into the DatatablesCriterias object to facilitate filtering
        for (ColumnDef columnDef : dataTableCriterias.getColumnDefs()) {
            switch (columnDef.getName()) {
                case "startDate":
                    columnDef.setSearch(request.getParameter("startDate"));
                    break;
                case "stopDate":
                    columnDef.setSearch(request.getParameter("stopDate"));
                    break;
            }
        }
        DataSet<Results> results = this.resultsServiceimpl.findResultsWithDatatablesCriterias(dataTableCriterias);
        return DatatablesResponse.build(results, dataTableCriterias);
    }
```

Comment: add what actually is sent to server for the params `startDate` and `stopDate`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check these-

- Can you check if startDate and stopDate values are getting set before making the call to the controller.
- You can also use @RequestParam(“startDate”) instead of HttpServletRequest. Refer Spring docs for more info - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestparam

Comment: I am familiar with this. The problem is in the ajax call which does not set the value before sending it to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Could try the following code please.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<Results> findAllForDataTables(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("startDate") String startDate, @RequestParam("stopDate") String stopDate) {

        System.out.println(startDate); 
         System.out.println(stopDate);

        // other stuff
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this shows nothing. I need to figure out why

Comment: I think if you serialize and pass it that way will help.

$.get('url', $('formName/Id').serialize(), json otherFields) and have the values as hidden fields in the page will get the values to your controller.

http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2011/01/29/ajax-post-to-spring-mvc-controller/

Answer (score 0):

Could try the following code please.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody DatatablesResponse<Results> findAllForDataTables(
              @RequestBody String startDate, @RequestBody String stopDate) {

}
```